# Check data consistency with prior in Bayesian setting

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, estimation

Let's say we are given an informative prior on $\theta$, preferably estimated from previous data.
Given some new observations, suppose the $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ is very deviating from what the prior specifies. In practice, we know that this may be due to some covariance shift. Is there some Bayesian methods, perhaps similar to hypo testing in frequentist setting, that can test whether $\theta$ has indeed shifted?

(P.S. Mainly, I am having trouble formatting this as a known academic topic and doing a subsequent google search. Would appreciate if anyone can simply point out some reference papers)

Comment: Something like comparing the prior and posterior distributions?

Comment: You might want to look at [Bousquet's](https://doi.org/10.1080/02664760802192981) Data Agreement Criterion (DAC).

Comment: Looks like a possible application for a multilevel/hierarchical model, where you allow both data sets to have different true $\theta$, yet you may want to do some partial pooling by putting a hyperprior. See e.g., [Chapter 5 of BDA](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/).